# Comparing and overlapping timeframes with three different data sets in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to sum up some time across two tables, but with some unusual conditions thrown in to complicate things.  I have two SQL tables -- Schedule and PunchClock -- both of which have three columns -- EmployeeID, StartTime and EndTime (both in datetime format).

I need to compare these two tables and determine the time frames of all of the time in the PunchClock table that falls outside of each employee's Schedule time.

For example, if Employee XYZ was scheduled from "2020-04-28 09:00" to "2020-04-28 17:00" in the Schedule table, but they punched in to the PunchClock table from "2020-04-28 08:45" to "2020-04-28 17:10", I need to know that their "non-scheduled work" time was from "2020-04-28 08:45" to "2020-04-28 09:00" as well as from "2020-04-28 17:00" to "2020-04-28 17:10".  I would need this regardless of how the two tables overlapped (or didn't overlap) as long as some portion of their PunchClock time fell OUTSIDE of their Scheduled time.

But to throw an extra wrench into this, I need to take this "non-scheduled work" time and find the total duration of "non-scheduled work" time that ONLY falls between 8:00-12:00 or 18:00-22:00 on any given day.

So back to my original example, from the "non-scheduled work" time, only the "2020-04-28 08:45" to "2020-04-28 09:00" time frame falls into this new condition.  Therefore the total PunchClock duration of Employee XYZ's time that BOTH falls outside of their Schedule time AND falls within the new criteria would be 15 minutes (i.e., 08:45 to 09:00).

I've tried to build the T-SQL several different ways and I keep getting close, but then run into roadblocks. Any help you can provide would be an enormous help? Thanks.

Comment: If you search for `[tsql] shift times` or `[tsql] overlap times` you may find some applicable questions and answers.

Comment: Already did. Found some things that got me close, but nothing I could use to get me to the solution. Or at least nothing I could figure out how to get me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compare time parts and use [case when] :
Im not sure if you want to (1)exclude punchClock outside maximum or (2)if you want to have the extra time limited to max interval.
here is (2). if you want (1), just add a where clause

```
declare @Schedule   table(EmployeeID int, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime);
declare @PunchClock table(EmployeeID int, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime);
insert @Schedule   values(1,'20200428 09:00','20200428 17:00'),(1,'20200429 09:00','20200429 17:00'),(1,'20200430 09:00','20200430 17:00');
insert @PunchClock values(1,'20200428 08:45','20200428 17:10'),(1,'20200429 07:53','20200429 22:03'),(1,'20200330 09:00','20200330 17:00')

declare @Tmin time(0) = '08:00';
declare @Tmax time(0) = '22:00';

select 
     [EmployeeID]   = ISNULL(s.EmployeeID, p.EmployeeID)
    ,[YYYYMMDD]     = ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(8), s.StartTime,112), CONVERT(CHAR(8), p.StartTime,112))
    ,[Sched StartTime] = s.StartTime
    ,[Sched EndTime]   = s.EndTime
    ,[Punch StartTime] = p.StartTime
    ,[Punch EndTime]   = p.EndTime

    ,[minutes overClock 1] = case when p.StartTime < s.StartTime then 
                                        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                                                 case when cast(p.StartTime as time(0)) < @Tmin then @Tmin else cast(p.StartTime as time(0)) end,
                                                 cast(s.StartTime as time(0))
                                                ) 
                             end
    ,[minutes overClock 2] = case when p.EndTime > s.EndTime then 
                                        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
                                                 cast(s.EndTime as time(0)), 
                                                 case when cast(p.EndTime as time(0)) > @Tmax then @Tmax else cast(p.EndTime as time(0)) end
                                                ) 
                             end

from @Schedule s
FULL OUTER JOIN @PunchClock p on p.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID /* same empID*/ and /*same day*/ CONVERT(CHAR(8),p.StartTime,112) = CONVERT(CHAR(8),s.StartTime,112)
ORDER BY [EmployeeID],[YYYYMMDD]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks so much. This is similar to one way I was coming at it as well.  What I discovered though was that it didn't cover cases when the punch and schedule didn't overlap at all. For example, if the punch was fully after the schedule record ended on a given day or if there was a punch record on a day when an employee wasn't scheduled at all.  Any further thoughts would be a huge help. Thanks again.

Comment: Also there are two valid time frames that the "non-scheduled" time has to fall within -- between 08:00-12:00 or between 18:00-22:00.  Otherwise I like what you have here.  I'm trying to see if I can adjust it to manage these other circumstances.

Comment: updated with FULL OUTER JOIN and isnull() to show id and dday in both cases if there is a punch without sched or sched without punch, but you'll  have to be more precise on what to compute in all cases and adapt the [case when] clause accordingly. also, you have to be sure that start and end datetimes are always the same day. otherwise the [where] and [case when] clause has to be more complex

Answer (score 0):

I took your queries, broke them up a bit and expanded them out.  Now it covers all of the scenarios I was looking for.  It may not be the most elegant of solutions but it's giving me exactly what I needed. Thanks for getting me started down the right path.

```
declare @Schedule   table (EmployeeID int, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime)
declare @PunchClock table (EmployeeID int, StartTime datetime, EndTime datetime)
declare @BonusShifts table (BonusStartTime TIME(0), BonusEndTime TIME(0))

insert @Schedule   
values  (1,'2020-04-21 09:00','2020-04-21 17:00'),
        (1,'2020-04-22 09:00','2020-04-22 17:00'),
        (1,'2020-04-23 09:00','2020-04-23 17:00'),
        (1,'2020-04-24 09:00','2020-04-24 17:00'),
        (1,'2020-04-25 09:00','2020-04-25 17:00'),
        (1,'2020-04-26 09:00','2020-04-26 17:00')

insert @PunchClock 
values  (1,'2020-04-21 09:45','2020-04-21 14:00'), /* punch fully inside sched */
        (1,'2020-04-22 08:30','2020-04-22 17:30'), /* punch fully outsite sched */
        (1,'2020-04-23 08:30','2020-04-23 16:30'), /* punch runs before sched with overlap */
        (1,'2020-04-24 09:30','2020-04-24 17:30'), /* punch runs after sched with overlap*/
        (1,'2020-04-25 07:00','2020-04-25 08:45'), /* punch fully before sched */
        (1,'2020-04-26 17:30','2020-04-26 22:00'), /* punch fully after sched */
        (1,'2020-04-27 09:00','2020-04-27 12:00')  /* punch with no sched */

insert into @BonusShifts
values  ('08:00','12:00'),
        ('18:00','22:00')

declare @WorkTable table (EmployeeID int, 
                            [SchedStartTime] datetime, 
                            [SchedEndTime] datetime, 
                            [PunchStartTime] datetime, 
                            [PunchEndTime] datetime, 
                            [ExtraStart] datetime,
                            [ExtraEnd] datetime
                            )

insert into @WorkTable
/** get punches BEFORE scheduled times or punches WITHOUT scheduled times **/
select 
  p.EmployeeID
  ,[SchedStartTime] = s.StartTime
  ,[SchedEndTime]   = s.EndTime

  ,[PunchStartTime] = p.StartTime
  ,[PunchEndTime]   = p.EndTime

  ,[EarlyExtraStart] = CASE WHEN p.StartTime < s.StartTime OR s.StartTime IS NULL THEN p.StartTime ELSE s.StartTime END
  ,[EarlyExtraEnd] = CASE WHEN p.StartTime < s.StartTime AND P.EndTime >= S.StartTime THEN s.StartTime 
                          WHEN p.StartTime < s.StartTime AND P.EndTime < S.StartTime THEN p.EndTime 
                          WHEN s.StartTime IS NULL THEN p.EndTime 
                          ELSE s.StartTime END
from @PunchClock p 
left join @Schedule s
    on p.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID 
    and CONVERT(CHAR(8),p.StartTime,112) = CONVERT(CHAR(8),s.StartTime,112)

UNION ALL

/** get punches AFTER scheduled times **/
select 
  p.EmployeeID
  ,[SchedStartTime] = s.StartTime
  ,[SchedEndTime]   = s.EndTime
  ,[PunchStartTime] = p.StartTime
  ,[PunchEndTime]   = p.EndTime
  ,[LateExtraStart] = CASE WHEN s.StartTime IS NULL THEN NULL
                           WHEN p.StartTime <= s.EndTime 
                           THEN s.EndTime ELSE p.StartTime END
  ,[LateExtraEnd] = CASE WHEN s.StartTime IS NULL THEN NULL
                         WHEN p.EndTime > s.EndTime THEN p.EndTime 
                         ELSE s.EndTime END
from @PunchClock p 
left join @Schedule s
    on p.EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID 
    and CONVERT(CHAR(8),p.StartTime,112) = CONVERT(CHAR(8),s.StartTime,112)

/** calculate durations for extra punch times that overlap bonus shift times **/
select *
    , [Overlap] = case when ExtraStart<>ExtraEnd AND CAST(ExtraStart AS TIME(0)) <= S.BonusEndTime and CAST(ExtraEnd AS TIME(0)) >= s.BonusStartTime then 'yes' else 'no' end
    , [OverlappingMinutes] = case when ExtraStart<>ExtraEnd AND CAST(ExtraStart AS TIME(0)) <= S.BonusEndTime and CAST(ExtraEnd AS TIME(0)) >= s.BonusStartTime then 
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE,case when CAST(ExtraStart AS TIME(0)) <= BonusStartTime THEN BonusStartTime ELSE CAST(ExtraStart AS TIME(0)) END
                          ,case when CAST(ExtraEnd AS TIME(0)) >= BonusEndTime THEN BonusEndTime ELSE CAST(ExtraEnd AS TIME(0)) END)
           ELSE 0 END
from @WorkTable W
cross join @BonusShifts S
ORDER BY EmployeeID,CONVERT(CHAR(8),W.PunchStartTime,112)
```